# video editing shading for 3D strip

Tags: rendering, shaders, video-sequence-editor, image

I use the blender video editor with several scenes.
The scenes contains images as planes (via the so-called addon).

They look good with a shading set to material in the 3D editor (render is also OK) :

[image]

But when I add them as scene strip, the look as grey boxes in the video preview (render is also KO) :

[image]

Is there any shading settings in the video sequencer ?

I'm using blender 2.90.1 on linux.

Comment: In vse preview sidebar, did you set the Scene Strip Display to Render?

Comment: Thanks a lot !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the VSE preview sidebar set the Scene Strip Display to Render :

[image]